# Multidimensional, associative array as config file for Bash script?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I'm making a simple bash script for live streaming using ffmpeg, but I'm not really sure how to properly make a config file for it.
If this was PHP, I would just use an array similar to the following one:

```
$platforms = array(
        array(
            "server" => "rtmp://twitch.tv",
            "stream_key" => "abc",
            "key_frame_interval" => "2"
        ),
        array(
            "server" => "rtmp://mixer.com",
            "stream_key" => "xyz",
            "key_frame_interval" => "4"
        )
    );
```

But since there aren't multidimensional arrays in Bash, I don't know how to make such a configuration file. What would be best-practice to represent this data in Bash?

Comment: In most languages, this is called a list of dictionaries, or hash tables.  Searching those terms instead of associative arrays may  turn up more results.

Answer (score 2):

In Bash, I think your best option will be to create multiple arrays, one per each key: `servers`, `stream_keys`, `key_frame_intervals`. Then, to build an "instance" of a configuration, you could build an associative array by piecing together values of the same index from the parallel arrays, for example:

```
declare -A config
config[server]=${servers[0]}
config[stream_key]=${stream_keys[0]}

for key in "${!config[@]}"; do
    echo "$key=${config[$key]}"
done
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, Janos! I got it working this way, however it doesn't look right to me. Do you know whether this technique is actually being used or is it more like a messy workaround?

Answer (score 2):

Technically, there's nothing to keep you from placing that structure (PHP/array) into your script's cfg/ini file ... you just need to write some code to parse said cfg/ini file.

Other options include xml, json, or a custom flat-file approach.  For the latter, something like:

```
# format:
# 
# ^platform|<server>|<stream_key>|<key_frame_interval>|

platform|rtmp://twitch.tv|abc|2|
platform|rtmp://mixer.com|xyz|4|
```

From here it's relatively simple to parse your config file looking for the desired data.

A couple considerations:

- look at all of your cfg/ini requirements and come up with a consistent format
- choose a field delimiter that won't show up in your field values (eg, '|' for the above example)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, @markp! Just wondering, would any of the approaches you mentioned considered best practice? (I get that it depends on the data in my config, but are there any conventions?)

Comment: re: best practice / conventions ... not really; besides the actual data there's a question of the program/scripts ability to read the cfg/ini file, ease of parsing the data, any need to share the cfg/ini file with other programs (ie, 'common' format), and what I would consider the biggest/main determiner ... personal preference